# Set div to start scrolling at a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element that scrolls with the user and stops when it reaches the footer of our webpage.

Im just trying to change it so it only starts scrolling when the user has scrolled 200px down the page. Cant see to get it working.

I had the scrolling working but when I tried wrapping an if statement of greater than 200 it stopped working.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { 
        var stopscroll = $("#footer").position();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < stopscroll.top - 900) {
                $(".demoForm")
                    .stop()
                    .animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px" }, "fast");
        }
    }
});
```

Just not sure why its breaking?

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is due to an unclosed conditional

```
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200{
```

Need to be changed to

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200){
```